# java.lang.StackOverflowError while doing deep recursion with Java 1.6 and Windows 7 OS

Tags: java, memory-management, stack-overflow

I have a program which will run into a very deep recursion while executing. In middle of this, I am getting `java.lang.StackOverflowError` and my application freezes. I am using JDK 1.6 and Windows 7 OS.

Strange thing here is, I am not getting this `StackOverflowError` with same code base while running my application with Java 1.5 and Windows XP. I understood that default stack size will differ from platform to platform and OS to OS. But with Java 1.5 and Windows XP, I set stack size of 256k using `-Xss` command and not getting this error. With same 256k in Windows 7 OS and Java 1.6, I am getting this error.

With stack size of 256k, my application is running without any issue in Windows XP and it's throwing a `StackOverflowError` in Windows 7 OS.

So please give any information how thread stack sizes will differ from Windows 7 OS to Windows XP??

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Hi. Its not a duplicate my friend. My question is, my application is running without any issue in WInodws Xp with stack size of 256k. But in Windows 7, its giving me stack overflow error with same stack size 256k. Increasing stack size in Windows 7 by -Xss will solve the problem. But strange thing, why its not working in windows 7 with same stack size??

Comment: Anyone knows in what unit 256k is? Bytes or frames? That *could* make a difference because then frames on a 64 bit system *could* be larger due to larger pointer size. Therefore less frames would fit into 256kB, assuming the unit is byte.

Answer (score 10):

I think the answer is, that the **JDK 1.5** ignores setting the default stack size to a specific value. Say, if you have a default stack size of 512K and (you believe that) you set it to 256K, finally it will still have a value of 512K. With the **JDK 6** you also set the default size to 256K, but here it really will have this value. That could be the reason, why your Windows 7 is getting the error (earlier)!

---

Look at this **-Xss Default Values** table:

```
Platform         Default
----------------------------------
Windows IA32     64 KB
Linux IA32       128 KB
Windows x86_64   128 KB
Linux x86_64     256 KB
Windows IA64     320 KB
Linux IA64       1024 KB (1 MB)
Solaris Sparc    512 KB
```

Here you can see, that the default values differ to the platform you're running on.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html#wp1024112

Furthermore, because you're getting a `StackOverflowError` on one system, but not the other, a 32-bit VM will store **addresses** with 4 bytes of memory. A 64-bit VM will store the same with 8-bytes! So, assuming you set the stack size value to 256K (yes, it's kBytes), a 32-bit system (probably your XP system) can store 65,536 addresses in its stack memory. A 64-bit system (your Windows 7 system) is only be able to store 32,768 addresses. This could be the issue between these two systems.

In general, Java **objects** consuming the same size of memory in a 32 as in a 64-bit VM. Obviously, if you have an `Object` which is referencing to 100 other `Object`s, it will increase the size of the main `Object` by 400 bytes on a 64-bit JVM.

Additionally it is said:

> Note that on some versions of Windows, the OS may round up thread
>   stack sizes using very coarse granularity. If the requested size is
>   less than the default size by 1K or more, the stack size is rounded up
>   to the default; otherwise, the stack size is rounded up to a multiple
>   of 1 MB.
>
> 64k is the least amount of stack space allowed per thread.

See: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#threads_oom

Unfortunately, I didn't find any concrete explanation, how the *coarse granularity* is being expressed.

Try to run the following sample program on both platforms to guess, how much the stack sizes differ between each other:

```
public class StackOverflowTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        recurse(0);
    }

    private static void recurse(int i) {
        try {
            recurse(++i);
        } catch (StackOverflowError e) {
            System.out.println(i);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

The results on my machine are:

```
Windows 7 (64-bit)

Stack calls     Java           Stack size
------------------------------------------
11424           JDK 5 64-bit   default
11424           JDK 5 64-bit   -Xss256K
11424           JDK 5 64-bit   -Xss1024K
6260            JRE 6 32-bit   default
4894            JRE 6 32-bit   -Xss256K
35405           JRE 6 32-bit   -Xss1024K
10448 to 10468  JDK 7 64-bit   default
2255 to 2274    JDK 7 64-bit   -Xss256K
10448 to 10468  JDK 7 64-bit   -Xss1024K
10396 to 41894  JDK 8 64-bit   default
2203 to 4590    JDK 8 64-bit   -Xss256K
10396 to 41894  JDK 8 64-bit   -Xss1024K
```

(**It would be great, if the list can be extended from other systems you're running on!**)

As you can see, the stack sizes are a complete mystery. It can be the fact, that the different Java versions consume different spaces in the stack memory.

Furthermore, if you set the stack size with `-Xss`, the value will be ignored on a Java 5 release.

With the JDK 7, you're not getting always the same result like on the other releases. The same goes to the JDK 8, where the ranges differ substantially.

Perhaps you can figure out yourself, if it only differs slighty or not on your own systems.

Further reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.2

> This specification permits Java Virtual Machine stacks **either to be of
>   a fixed size or to dynamically expand** and contract as required by the
>   computation. If the Java Virtual Machine stacks are of a fixed size,
>   the size of each Java Virtual Machine stack may be chosen
>   independently when that stack is created.

So, the question is, what is meant by *dynamically expand*?

Then I discovered a bug in the sources, that could be of interest, if you're running on an earlier Java 6 release:

http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6316197

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Now its clear that default stack size will differ from platform to platform. But if we set same stack size in windows xp and windows 7, application is running successfully in windows xp and its failing in windows 7. is there any reason. Highly appreciate your reply on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing, that your Windows 7 system is a 64 bit version and your XP a 32 bit. So this could possible make the difference how the memory is being used!

Comment: I've extended my answer to distinguish the 32 and the 64-bit systems.

Comment: Hi. Your explanation on difference between 32-bit and 64-bit version is making sense to me and may be its truw. But, I am using 32-bit version for both Windows XP and Windows 7. In this case, memory consumption will make any difference??

Comment: I've changed my answer and added a sample program that you could try to execute on both platforms. May be, you can figure something out! Your question is in fact a really good one ;)

Comment: Hey Thanks for your help. Your information and link provided really helped me a lot to understand the issue. Thanks again for helping. I understood that default stack size for java 6 in winodws is 320k. Do u have any idea what is the default size of stack size java 5? In java 5, jvm is not considering the value paasing using -Xss. It is always doing 12,472 recursions whatever the size u set from -Xss.

Comment: I added some benchmark results to different Java versions (and also provided a better benchmark test program). It's very curious... Would be nice, if you can provide your results on your XP and Win7 system with 32-bit!

Comment: @bobbel: `In general, Java objects consuming the same size of memory in a 32 as in a 64-bit VM.`  Are you sure?  Objects are referenced ultimately via a memory pointer.  Object references will be larger, as will the space needed to reference any objects the original object defines as properties or fields.

Comment: Well, you're probably right, that the **references** in a Java object will increase the memory consumption of the object itself. But the **data** itself won't increase it. Obviously, if you have an `Object` which is referencing to 100 other `Object`s, it will increase the size of the main `Object` by 400 bytes on a 64-bit JVM. So, good point here from you!