# Stack size verification and StackOverflowError

Tags: java, stack, stack-size

In Java, each thread will have some stack memory allocated to it which is defined by `-Xss` parameter and there is some default value.

Now, I overridden the default stack size by running below code as `java -Xss1k Test`.

**Last output:**

```
18479
18480Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

**Questions:**

- Why values till 18479 printed? I was expecting far less values because I mentioned stack size of 1KB and was storing an int on each stack frame.
- With 1KB or 1024 bytes of stack size, only 256 (1024/4) int values could be storable. No? Because with each recursive call one stack frame will be added and int will be stored on it. So, as soon as 256 stack frames with size of 4 bytes each are added there should have been StackOverflowError.
- My understanding is that the global scoped `counter` will not contribute in any way to the stack consumption because it will live in old gen space. Confirm?

```
 public class Test {
    private static int counter = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getMeStackOverflowException();
    }

    private static void getMeStackOverflowException(){
        int x = 123;
        System.out.println(Test.counter++);
        getMeStackOverflowException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> With 1KB or 1024 bytes of stack size, only 256 (1024/4) int values could be storable. No?

No.  The return address is also stored on the stack, so you should overflow in fewer than 256 recursive calls.

> My understanding is that the global scoped x will not contribute in any way to the stack consumption because it will live in old gen space. Confirm?

Confirmed.

For Windows:

> Note that on some versions of Windows, the OS may round up thread stack sizes using very coarse granularity. If the requested size is less than the default size by 1K or more, the stack size is rounded up to the default; otherwise, the stack size is rounded up to a multiple of 1 MB

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21404616/141172).

Comment: Sorry, I one point added. I really want to why values till 18479 got printed. I was expecting far less values because I mentioned stack size of 1KB and was storing an int on each stack frame.

Comment: "The return address is also stored on the stack" Which return address, of last method stack frame ?? Could you please elaborate ??

Comment: "you should overflow in fewer than 256 recursive calls." Yes, but it didn't, and that's where I am unable to understand the reason.

Comment: When any method is called, the current method's resume-at address is placed on the stack along with any parameters passed on the stack.  When the new method takes control, it further expands the stack to create any local variables.  All of this assumes no JIT optimizations such as method inlining or passing parameters in registers / allocating local variables to registers.  As for why you get such a large output, there has been a history of -Xss being ignored in some Java versions.  See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/21404616/141172.  Perhaps that applies in your case.

Comment: Even it is taking default size of 64KB (I am using Windows 7) then also 64*1024=65536 bytes of stack size. Now, 4 bytes of int and 1 byte of memory address mean 5 bytes, so maximum iterations should have been ~13107. But I got 18480.

Comment: On Windows `Note that on some versions of Windows, the OS may round up thread stack sizes using very coarse granularity. If the requested size is less than the default size by 1K or more, the stack size is rounded up to the default; otherwise, the stack size is rounded up to a multiple of 1 MB.` (from the previous link)

Comment: `and 1 byte of memory address` A memory address is 4 bytes (32-bit) or 8 bytes (64-bit).

Comment: Sorry, my bad, 4 bytes of memory location for 32 bit processor. Let me try in 64 and 32 bit Ubuntu but in case of Window, still with default size of 64KB or getting 1MB, 18480 is not understandable.